# How to sync scrolling first-positions of 2 RecyclerViews?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

### Background

I have 2 RecyclerView instances. One is horizontal, and the second is vertical.

They both show the same data and have the same amount of items, but in different ways, and the cells are not necessary equal in size through each of them .

I wish that scrolling in one will sync with the other, so that the first item that's shown on one, will always be shown on the other (as the first).

### The problem

Even though I've succeeded making them sync (I just choose which one is the "master", to control the scrolling of the other), the direction of the scrolling seems to affect the way it works.

Suppose for a moment the cells have equal heeight:

If I scroll up/left, it works as I intended, more or less:

[image]

However, if I scroll down/right, it does let the other RecyclerView show the first item of the other, but usually not as the first item:

[image]

Note: on the above screenshots, I've scrolled in the bottom RecyclerView, but a similar result will be with the top one.

The situation gets much worse if, as I wrote, the cells have different sizes:

[image]

### What I've tried

I tried to use other ways of scrolling and going to other positions, but all attempts fail.

Using smoothScrollToPosition made things even worse (though it does seem nicer), because if I fling, at some point the other RecyclerView takes control of the one I've interacted with.

I think I should use the direction of the scrolling, together with the currently shown items on the other RecyclerView.

Here's the current (sample) code. Note that in the real code, the cells might not have equal sizes (some are tall, some are short, etc...). One of the lines in the code makes the cells have different height.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/topReccyclerView" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:layout_marginStart="8dp" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" tools:listitem="@layout/horizontal_cell"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/bottomRecyclerView" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/topReccyclerView"
        tools:listitem="@layout/horizontal_cell"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**horizontal_cell.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:gravity="center" tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem"/>
```

**vertical_cell.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center" tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem"/>
```

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var masterView: View? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this)
        topReccyclerView.adapter = object : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
            override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
                (holder.itemView as TextView).text = position.toString()
                holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(if(position%2==0) 0xffff0000.toInt() else 0xff00ff00.toInt())
            }

            override fun getItemCount(): Int {
                return 100
            }

            override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
                return object : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.horizontal_cell, parent, false)) {}
            }
        }

        bottomRecyclerView.adapter = object : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
        val baseHeight = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50f, resources.displayMetrics).toInt()

            override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
                (holder.itemView as TextView).text = position.toString()
                holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(if(position%2==0) 0xffff0000.toInt() else 0xff00ff00.toInt())
                // this makes the heights of the cells different from one another:
                holder.itemView.layoutParams.height = baseHeight + (if (position % 3 == 0) 0 else baseHeight / (position % 3))
            }

            override fun getItemCount(): Int {
                return 100
            }

            override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
                return object : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.vertical_cell, parent, false)) {}
            }
        }
        LinearSnapHelper().attachToRecyclerView(topReccyclerView)
        LinearSnapHelper().attachToRecyclerView(bottomRecyclerView)
        topReccyclerView.addOnScrollListener(OnScrollListener(topReccyclerView, bottomRecyclerView))
        bottomRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(OnScrollListener(bottomRecyclerView, topReccyclerView))
    }

    inner class OnScrollListener(private val thisRecyclerView: RecyclerView, private val otherRecyclerView: RecyclerView) : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        var lastItemPos: Int = Int.MIN_VALUE
        val thisRecyclerViewId = resources.getResourceEntryName(thisRecyclerView.id)

        override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView?, newState: Int) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
            Log.d("AppLog", "onScrollStateChanged:$thisRecyclerViewId $newState")
            when (newState) {
                RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING -> if (masterView == null) {
                    Log.d("AppLog", "setting $thisRecyclerViewId to be master")
                    masterView = thisRecyclerView
                }
                RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE -> if (masterView == thisRecyclerView) {
                    Log.d("AppLog", "resetting $thisRecyclerViewId from being master")
                    masterView = null
                    lastItemPos = Int.MIN_VALUE
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView?, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
            if ((dx == 0 && dy == 0) || (masterView != null && masterView != thisRecyclerView))
                return
            //            Log.d("AppLog", "onScrolled:$thisRecyclerView $dx-$dy")
            val currentItem = (thisRecyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
            if (lastItemPos == currentItem)
                return
            lastItemPos = currentItem
            otherRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(currentItem)
//            otherRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(currentItem)
            Log.d("AppLog", "currentItem:" + currentItem)
        }
    }
}
```

### The questions

1. How do I let the other RecycerView to always have the first item the same as the currently controlled one?
2. How to modify the code to support smooth scrolling, without causing the issue of suddenly having the other RecyclerView being the one that controls ?

---

EDIT: after updating the sample code here with having different sizes of cells (because originally that's closer to the issue I have, as I described before), I noticed that the snapping doesn't work well.

That's why I chose to use this library to snap it correctly:

https://github.com/DevExchanges/SnappingRecyclerview

So instead of LinearSnapHelper, I use 'GravitySnapHelper'. Seems to work better, but still have the syncing issues, and touching while it scrolls.

---

EDIT:
I've finally fixed all syncing issues, and it works fine even if the cells have different sizes.

Still has some issues:

1. If you fling on one RecyclerView, and then touch the other one, it has very weird behavior of scrolling. Might scroll way more than it should.
2. The scrolling isn't smooth (when syncing and when flinging), so it doesn't look well.
3. Sadly, because of the snapping (which I actually might need only for the top RecyclerView), it causes another issue: the bottom RecyclerView might show the last item partially (screenshot with 100 items), and I can't scroll more to show it fully :

[image]

I don't even think that the bottom RecyclerView should be snapping, unless the top one was touched. Sadly this is all I got so far, that has no syncing issues.

Here's the new code, after all the fixes I've found:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var masterView: View? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this)
        topReccyclerView.adapter = object : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
            override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
                (holder.itemView as TextView).text = position.toString()
                holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(if (position % 2 == 0) 0xffff0000.toInt() else 0xff00ff00.toInt())
            }

            override fun getItemCount(): Int = 1000

            override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
                return object : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.horizontal_cell, parent, false)) {}
            }
        }

        bottomRecyclerView.adapter = object : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
            val baseHeight = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50f, resources.displayMetrics).toInt()
            override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
                (holder.itemView as TextView).text = position.toString()
                holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(if (position % 2 == 0) 0xffff0000.toInt() else 0xff00ff00.toInt())
                holder.itemView.layoutParams.height = baseHeight + (if (position % 3 == 0) 0 else baseHeight / (position % 3))
            }

            override fun getItemCount(): Int = 1000

            override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
                return object : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.vertical_cell, parent, false)) {}
            }
        }
        // GravitySnapHelper is available from : https://github.com/DevExchanges/SnappingRecyclerview
        GravitySnapHelper(Gravity.START).attachToRecyclerView(topReccyclerView)
        GravitySnapHelper(Gravity.TOP).attachToRecyclerView(bottomRecyclerView)
        topReccyclerView.addOnScrollListener(OnScrollListener(topReccyclerView, bottomRecyclerView))
        bottomRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(OnScrollListener(bottomRecyclerView, topReccyclerView))
    }

    inner class OnScrollListener(private val thisRecyclerView: RecyclerView, private val otherRecyclerView: RecyclerView) : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        var lastItemPos: Int = Int.MIN_VALUE
        val thisRecyclerViewId = resources.getResourceEntryName(thisRecyclerView.id)

        override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView?, newState: Int) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
            when (newState) {
                RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING -> if (masterView == null) {
                    masterView = thisRecyclerView
                }
                RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE -> if (masterView == thisRecyclerView) {
                    masterView = null
                    lastItemPos = Int.MIN_VALUE
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView?, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
            if (dx == 0 && dy == 0 || masterView !== null && masterView !== thisRecyclerView) {
                return
            }
            val otherLayoutManager = otherRecyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager
            val thisLayoutManager = thisRecyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager
            val currentItem = thisLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
            if (lastItemPos == currentItem) {
                return
            }
            lastItemPos = currentItem
            otherLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(currentItem, 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: edit your screenshot, they seem broken.

Comment: In my browser, they render just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Combining the two `RecyclerView`s, there are four cases of movement:

a. Scrolling the horizontal recycler to the left

b. Scrolling it to the right

c. Scrolling the vertical recycler to the top

d. Scrolling it to the bottom

Cases a and c don't need to be taken care of since they work out of the box. For cases b and d you need to do two things:

1. Know which recycler you are in (vertical or horizontal) and which direction the scroll went (up or down resp. left or right) and
2. calculate an offset (of list items) from the number of visible items in `otherRecyclerView` (if the screen is bigger the offset needs to be bigger, too).

Figuring this out was a bit fiddly, but the result is pretty straight forward.

```
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
            if (masterView == otherRecyclerView) {
                thisRecyclerView.stopScroll();
                otherRecyclerView.stopScroll();
                syncScroll(1, 1);
            }
            masterView = thisRecyclerView;
        } else if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE && masterView == thisRecyclerView) {
            masterView = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerview, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerview, dx, dy);
        if ((dx == 0 && dy == 0) || (masterView != null && masterView != thisRecyclerView)) {
            return;
        }
        syncScroll(dx, dy);
    }

    void syncScroll(int dx, int dy) {
        LinearLayoutManager otherLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) otherRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
        LinearLayoutManager thisLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) thisRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
        int offset = 0;
        if ((thisLayoutManager.getOrientation() == HORIZONTAL && dx > 0) || (thisLayoutManager.getOrientation() == VERTICAL && dy > 0)) {
            // scrolling horizontal recycler to left or vertical recycler to bottom
            offset = otherLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() - otherLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
        }
        int currentItem = thisLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
        otherLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(currentItem, offset);
    }
```

Of course you could combine the two if clauses since the bodies are the same. For the sake of readability, I thought it is good to keep them apart.

The second problem was syncing when the respective "other" recycler was touched while the "first" recycler was still scrolling. Here the following code (included above) is relevant:

```
if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
    if (masterView == otherRecyclerView) {
        thisRecyclerView.stopScroll();
        otherRecyclerView.stopScroll();
        syncScroll(1, 1);
    }
    masterView = thisRecyclerView;
}
```

`newState` equals `SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING` when the recycler is touched and dragged a little bit. So if this is a touch (& drag) after a touch on the respective "other" recycler, the second condition `(masterView == otherRecyclerview)` is true. Both recyclers are stopped then and the "other" recycler is synced with "this" one.

Comment: This works, but `smoothScrollToPosition` can cause issues. Try to fling on one RecyclerView, and then touch the other while both are scrolling. I think it causes something similar to race-condition. Now that I've tried it, it occurs even when I use `scrollToPosition` instead. What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Okay, I see. There is a way to get the two lists out of sync. Hold on, I will fix this, too.

Comment: Do you know why this occurs? Maybe I should make them both stop scrolling and let the one that the user touches, to be the master and set where to stop.

Comment: I don't see what you changed. Also, can you please show how to do what I wrote? That once the user touches the view, it becomes the master and stops them both from scrolling... ?

Comment: I think the code also has issues in case there are non equal sizes of items: it might scroll to the correct item almost perfectly as the first item, as there would still be the item before of it shown, just partially. I need to make a better POC to show this specific issue, if you wish. I wrote about it in the POC in the question, just for simplicity (and wrote a note about it too), as I believed that this won't be an issue.

Comment: The current version is not perfect, but it works reasonably well. To improve it, the touch&drag event necessary to stop the other recycler by touching this one, would have to be replaces by a simple touch event.

Comment: If you mean the check of "SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING", it indeed doesn't work. It doesn't get caught when touching while it scrolls. Also, you removed the `lastItemPos` I was using to filter out un-needed events (as we are still on the same position, so no need to scroll again). Another issue that I have, which I wrote before (and in the description of the question), is that the items don't necessary have the same height. I've updated the question to have this code, to make it easier to check.

Comment: I think the reason I have the issue of different cells sizes, is because of LinearSnapHelper, which snaps to the middle visible item, instead of the the first one. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: OK, noticed the snapping can be solved by using a library from here: https://github.com/DevExchanges/SnappingRecyclerview . Still, it has syncing issues and the touch-while-scrolling issue :(

Comment: OK, I've fixed all except for the touch-while-scrolling issue, and that sadly my solution doesn't support smooth scrolling. Please, if you know how to fix it, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

**1-) Layout manager**

The current `smoothScrollToPosition` does not take the element to the top. So let's write a new layout manager. And let's override this layout manager's `smoothScrollToPosition`.

```
public class TopLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager
{
    public TopLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation)
    {
        //orientation : vertical or horizontal
        super(context, orientation, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state, int position)
    {
        RecyclerView.SmoothScroller smoothScroller = new TopSmoothScroller(recyclerView.getContext());
        smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
        startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
    }

    private class TopSmoothScroller extends LinearSmoothScroller
    {
        TopSmoothScroller(Context context)
        {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        public int calculateDtToFit(int viewStart, int viewEnd, int boxStart, int boxEnd, int snapPreference)
        {
            return (boxStart - viewStart);
        }
    }
}
```

**2-) Setup**

```
    //horizontal one
    RecyclerView rvMario = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvMario);

    //vertical one
    RecyclerView rvLuigi = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvLuigi);

    final LinearLayoutManager managerMario = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    rvMario.setLayoutManager(managerMario);
    ItemMarioAdapter adapterMario = new ItemMarioAdapter(itemList);
    rvMario.setAdapter(adapterMario);

     //Snap to start by using Ruben Sousa's RecyclerViewSnap
    SnapHelper snapHelper = new GravitySnapHelper(Gravity.START);
    snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rvMario);

    final TopLinearLayoutManager managerLuigi = new TopLinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    rvLuigi.setLayoutManager(managerLuigi);
    ItemLuigiAdapter adapterLuigi = new ItemLuigiAdapter(itemList);
    rvLuigi.setAdapter(adapterLuigi);
```

**3-) Scroll listener**

```
rvMario.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)
    {
     super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

     //get firstCompleteleyVisibleItemPosition
     int firstCompleteleyVisibleItemPosition = managerMario.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

     if (firstCompleteleyVisibleItemPosition >= 0)
     {  
      //vertical one, smooth scroll to position
      rvLuigi.smoothScrollToPosition(firstCompleteleyVisibleItemPosition);
     }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState)
    {
     super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
    }
});
```

**4-) Output**

[image]

Comment: Looks promissing, but works for only one `RecyclerView`. If I add the same `OnScrollListener` to the other, things get really slow and fling is not possible anymore.

Comment: It has some issues: the bottom RecyclerView doesn't sync with the top one. flinging on the top doesn't scroll as well and fast as on the bottom one.  3. Trying to add syncing at the bottom as you did for the top will cause other scrolling issues, not allowing to do smooth scrolling by flinguing. Also, a side note: please either provide full code or use same names of variables and other stuff as I've written. It's enough that you guys write on Java every time, even though the code is in Kotlin (I need to convert every time...).

Comment: What does this code do: `return (boxStart + (boxEnd - boxStart) / 1000) - (viewStart + (viewEnd - viewStart) / 1000);`? Why do you devide by 1000?

Comment: @KalaBalik Good question. The docs are here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearSmoothScroller.html#calculateDtToFit(int, int, int, int, int) . Sadly, I don't understand what it means, even after reading. It returns amount of scroll needed to determine if the view should be visible?!

Comment: i guess i misunderstood. The example i have given is valid only in situation where one recyclerview synchs the other. 

@KalaBalik divide by 1000 means nothing, i accidentally posted something like I tried. I have updated what it should be.

boxStart means y axis of top of recyclerview, viewStart means y axis of top of view. boxStart - viewStart calculates the amount of scrolling required to display the view at the given position at the top. According to the direction of the scroll, sometimes it will be negative and sometimes positive.

Comment: for ex : if we change the relevant code line like return (boxStart + (boxEnd - boxStart) / 2) - (viewStart + (viewEnd - viewStart) / 2) does display the view at the given position at the center.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Burak's `TopLinearLayoutManager`, but correcting the logic of the `OnScrollListener` we finally get working smoothscrolling and correct snapping (of the horizontal `RecyclerView`).

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    View masterView = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);
        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        final RecyclerView topRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.topReccyclerView);
        RecyclerView.Adapter adapterTop = new RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
            @Override
            public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                return new ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.horizontal_cell, parent, false));
            }

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
                ((TextView) holder.itemView).setText(String.valueOf(position));
                holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(position % 2 == 0 ? Integer.valueOf(0xffff0000) : Integer.valueOf(0xff00ff00));
            }

            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return 100;
            }

            class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
                final TextView textView;

                ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                    super(itemView);
                    textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
                }
            }
        };
        topRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapterTop);

        final RecyclerView bottomRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.bottomRecyclerView);
        RecyclerView.Adapter adapterBottom = new RecyclerView.Adapter() {
            int baseHeight = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50f, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

            @Override
            public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                return new ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.vertical_cell, parent, false));
            }

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
                ((TextView) holder.itemView).setText(String.valueOf(position));
                holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor((position % 2 == 0) ? Integer.valueOf(0xffff0000) : Integer.valueOf(0xff00ff00));
                holder.itemView.getLayoutParams().height = baseHeight + (position % 3 == 0 ? 0 : baseHeight / (position % 3));
            }

            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return 100;
            }

            class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
                final TextView textView;

                ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                    super(itemView);
                    textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
                }
            }
        };
        bottomRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapterBottom);

        TopLinearLayoutManager topLayoutManager = new TopLinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
        topRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(topLayoutManager);
        TopLinearLayoutManager bottomLayoutManager = new TopLinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        bottomRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(bottomLayoutManager);

        final OnScrollListener topOnScrollListener = new OnScrollListener(topRecyclerView, bottomRecyclerView);
        final OnScrollListener bottomOnScrollListener = new OnScrollListener(bottomRecyclerView, topRecyclerView);
        topRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(topOnScrollListener);
        bottomRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(bottomOnScrollListener);

        GravitySnapHelper snapHelperTop = new GravitySnapHelper(Gravity.START);
        snapHelperTop.attachToRecyclerView(topRecyclerView);
    }

    class OnScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
        private RecyclerView thisRecyclerView;
        private RecyclerView otherRecyclerView;
        int lastItemPos = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        OnScrollListener(RecyclerView thisRecyclerView, RecyclerView otherRecyclerView) {
            this.thisRecyclerView = thisRecyclerView;
            this.otherRecyclerView = otherRecyclerView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
                masterView = thisRecyclerView;
            } else if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE && masterView == thisRecyclerView) {
                masterView = null;
                lastItemPos = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerview, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerview, dx, dy);
            if ((dx == 0 && dy == 0) || (masterView != thisRecyclerView)) {
                return;
            }
            int currentItem = ((TopLinearLayoutManager) thisRecyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            if (lastItemPos == currentItem) {
                return;
            }
            lastItemPos = currentItem;
            otherRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(otherRecyclerView, null, currentItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It has multiple issues: 1. small fling left on the top recyclerView jumps a cell at the end of its snapping. 2. fling left on the top to cell "0", and the bottom might reach "1" instead. 3. scrolling doesn't seem fast at the top as at the bottom. 3. at the bottom, if you fast-fling to reach the top, it stops at some other place instead. Sometimes can be barely scrolling.

Comment: Small change in `OnScrolled` (see [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47495438/revisions)) to address 1. and, I believe, 2., too. Number 3 is the result of longer fling distances and higher fling velocities on the bottom view. And 4. I cannot reproduce.

Comment: 1. Seems ok now. 2. You can have a 1-difference by fling at the top RecyclerView, and then stop it by touching it again. 3. Should be smooth, just as on the other RecyclerView. 4. Seems very rare now. Try to do it when being at the bottom. 5. If you fling at the bottom recyclerView (up/down), and then stop it by touching the top one, they are not synced anymore. See what I got : https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qli9.png . 6. If I fling at the top RecyclerView, to go to the right, and then touch the bottom RecyclerView, it can be even worse : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztsWw.png

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution working fine in my device

**Variable**

```
RecyclerView horizontalRecyclerView, verticalRecyclerView;
LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManager, verticalLayoutManager;

ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> arrayList2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

**`RecyclerView` code**

```
horizontalRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.horizontalRc);
verticalRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.verticalRc);

horizontalRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
verticalRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

horizontalLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
verticalLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

horizontalRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManager);
verticalRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(verticalLayoutManager);

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
     arrayList.add("" + i);
     arrayList2.add("" + i);
 }

 MyDataAdapter horizontalAdapter = new MyDataAdapter(this, arrayList);
 MyDataAdapter verticalAdapter = new MyDataAdapter(this, arrayList2);

 horizontalRecyclerView.setAdapter(horizontalAdapter);
 verticalRecyclerView.setAdapter(verticalAdapter);
```

logic inside **`RecyclerView.addOnScrollListener`**

```
 horizontalRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                int pos = horizontalLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                verticalLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(pos, 20);

            }

        });


        verticalRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                int pos = verticalLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                horizontalLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(pos, 20);


            }
        });
```

Hope it help some one

**WHOLE Code**

```
public class Main4Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView horizontalRecyclerView, verticalRecyclerView;
    LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManager, verticalLayoutManager;

    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> arrayList2 = new ArrayList<>();

    boolean isVertical = true, isHorizontal = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);


        horizontalRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.horizontalRc);
        verticalRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.verticalRc);

        horizontalRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        verticalRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        horizontalLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        verticalLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

        horizontalRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManager);
        verticalRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(verticalLayoutManager);

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            arrayList.add("" + i);
            arrayList2.add("" + i);
        }

        MyDataAdapter horizontalAdapter = new MyDataAdapter(this, arrayList);
        MyDataAdapter verticalAdapter = new MyDataAdapter(this, arrayList2);

        horizontalRecyclerView.setAdapter(horizontalAdapter);
        verticalRecyclerView.setAdapter(verticalAdapter);

        horizontalRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                int pos = horizontalLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                verticalLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(pos, 20);


            }

        });


        verticalRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                int pos = verticalLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                horizontalLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(pos, 20);


            }
        });



       /* horizontalRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                int pos = horizontalLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                verticalLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(pos, 20);

                *//*if (isHorizontal) {
                    int pos = horizontalLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                    verticalLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(pos, 20);
                    Log.e("isHorizontal", "TRUE");
                    isVertical = false;
                } else {
                    isHorizontal = true;
                }*//*

            }

           *//* @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                isVertical = true;
            }*//*
        });


        verticalRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

            *//* @Override
             public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                 super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                 isHorizontal = true;
             }
 *//*
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                int pos = verticalLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                horizontalLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(pos, 20);

               *//* if (isVertical) {
                    int pos = verticalLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                    horizontalLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(pos, 20);
                    Log.e("isVertical", "TRUE");
                    isHorizontal = false;
                } else {
                    isVertical = true;
                }*//*


            }
        });*/


    }
}
```

**Adapter code**

```
public class MyDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyDataAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList;


    public MyDataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyDataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.temp, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyDataAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            holder.tvNumber.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorGreen);
        } else {
            holder.tvNumber.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorRed);
        }
        holder.tvNumber.setText(arrayList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tvNumber;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

**Activity layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalRc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/verticalRc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />



</LinearLayout>
```

**temp Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="40dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="50dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**COLOR**

```
<color name="colorGreen">#307832</color>
<color name="colorRed">#ff4c4c</color>
```

Comment: What's the 20 ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper sir calling `scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, 20)` will layout such that item[position]'s bottom is 20 pixels above the RecyclerView's bottom.  info from docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#scrollToPositionWithOffset(int,%20int)

Comment: Why put it 20 pixels above its bottom?

Comment: @androiddeveloper sir it was just for test case i have put 20 pixels we can also set 0 insetad of 20

Comment: Can you please show entire code? I remember I've went through a lot of issues, and I have already tried scrollToPositionWithOffset. It had some issue that prevented me from using it.

Comment: I can't. It lacks some XML and resources files you've changed compared to what I did.

Comment: @androiddeveloper i have provided layout files please check it

Comment: I don't see "temp" layout, and other resources.

Comment: @androiddeveloper i have added all resources let me know if any  missed

Comment: Sorry forgot to try it. The layout file has `android:visibility="gone"` for some reason, so I didn't see anything. Had to remove it, and also name MainActivity instead of the extra "4" in everything. Also , slow scroll-right on the top RecyclerView makes a "crazy" scrolling on both of them. See video here: https://ufile.io/6l189