# DiffUtil - How to keep the old List before updating it

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to use `DiffUtil` to update a `RecyclerView`. I have a class `DataProvider` which is a singleton class that holds the List which contains the Objects.

Every time I need to update the `RecyclerView` I modify the List in `DataProvider`. Now when I try to use the `DiffUtil` which takes two lists as parameters I don't really have the old `List` anymore, because I updated it.

What is the best way to keep the old `List` before updating it, so that I can compare them and do the needed updates on the `RecyclerView` without having to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47522246/8298909

I understand that you're asking a different question, but the two code snippets in my linked answer are almost exactly what you're looking for: a simple implementation of `DiffUtil.Callback` and an example of how to use it even when you're directly modifying the data source that backs your adapter.

The key is to create a (temporary) copy of the pre-modification list by using `new ArrayList<>([your data here])` before executing your changes.

Comment: Wouldn't that just create a reference to the same `List` and whenever I modify the new list the old one will also get modified?

Comment: Because when I check the debugger the Lists both have different IDs for example `ArrayList@5162` and `ArrayList@5163`, but when I check the items inside they all reference to the same object, for example the 1st item in the `oldList` is `Item@5238` which is the same as in the `newList`

Comment: @Enve, would you post your solution if you found it ? I am facing the same issue...