# How can i make recycler view go to first position from last

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using recyclerview in my project. its orientation is horizontal. There are only 4 items in it. I want make it move in in circular form. What i mean is when user is on 4th item and swipes left the first item should be displayed. Now it just stops in the end.

Comment: Can you provide us what you have done so far?

Comment: You are looking for a circular recyclerview. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31253555/how-do-i-create-a-circular-endless-recyclerview

Comment: look and visit this link --
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37784868/how-to-create-closed-circular-recyclerview-with-custom-recycler-adapter

Comment: Just a regular Recycler adapter @FedericoNavarrete

Comment: You must create a new custom layout manager. Check [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47491209/5392118)

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be make item count of RecyclerView Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Update your RecyclerView Adapter as

```
@Override
public int getItemCount(){
    return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

Then while getting item for position

```
MyClass getItem(int position) {
    int positionInList = position % myList.size();
    return myList.get(positionInList);
}
```

Then OnBindViewHolder ..

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position);
       MyClass item = getItem(position);
     // use item as required here
}
```

Comment: I am using Firebase Adapter